# codeigniter - form submission mistake

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

i made a normal form for users to submit data name,email and city in form for this work i use some coding and i still not figure out where i mistaken please suggest.

routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

welcome.php in controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('ar_signup');     
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
}
```

ar_signup for the form in view

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="assests/css/ar/ar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <?php echo form_open('user'); ?>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="name" id="name" name="name">   
        <label for="email">Email:</label>       
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">        
        <label for="city">City:</label>     
        <input type="city" id="city" name="city">       
        <input type="submit" value="Login">     
        </div>      
        </form>     

  </body>
</html>
```

user.php in controller

```
<?php
function create_member()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');        

        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'trim|required');     

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('ar_thanks');
        }
        else
        {           
            $this->load->model('users_model');

            if($query = $this->Users_model->create_member())
            {
                $this->load->view('ar_landing');            
            }

        }

    }
```

user_model.php mention in models

```
<?php
function create_member()
    {

        $this->db->where('user_name', $this->input->post('username'));
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows > 0){           
        }else{
            $new_member_insert_data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'city' => $this->input->post('city'),                           
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_member_insert_data);
            return $insert;
        }

    }//create_member
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? Do you have any errors?

Comment: where is your `$this->load->helper('form');`?

Comment: in autoload i add $autoload['helpers'] = array('form');

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: when i submit the form its shows, 

Not Found

The requested URL /landingpage/user was not found on this server.

Comment: try to replace `<?php echo form_open('user'); ?>` with `<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>/user" method='post'`

Answer (score 0):

In Your user.php controller change

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('ar_thanks');
    }
```

to

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('ar_signup');
    }
```

In your view file give this: `<?php echo form_open('user/create_member'); ?>`

Now hit the ur: **localhost/landingpage/index.php/user/create_member**

Comment: i already check this its not working even in default index i test all i done it already but i dont understand where is the mistake.

Comment: do `<?php echo form_close(); ?>` instead of `</form>`

Comment: still the same nothing change!

Comment: what is your project url?also change `<link href="assests/css/ar/ar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` to `<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assests/css/ar/ar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url() in C:\wamp\www\landingpage\application\views\ar_signup.php on line 6 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0000152376{main}( )..\index.php:0 20.0000188440require_once( 

cont...

Comment: give your config details and your folder structure.Also give the url on how you are accessing this view page.

Comment: '$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/landingpage';'

$config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: application is main folder then all are sub.
-attachements,-cache,-config,-controllers,-core,-erros,-helpers,-language,-logs,-models

Comment: have you removed index.php by .htaccess?Give the url that you are hitting on browser.

Comment: give this `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'` and check

Comment: already tried and checked but the error is same, 404 not found

Comment: no i can change the controller name too np i just need to run the form and submit data in database nothing else name of pages not imp.

Comment: ok.editing my answer.just keep `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'`

Comment: checked still the same problem. :(

Comment: Remove all the php codes from view page and see if simple html is also working or not by hitting  `localhost/landingpage`

Comment: i remove 3 lines of php echo and test page opening perfectly when i click on login its not working because no function there.

Comment: may be some problem in your codeigniter installation try to reinstall fresh one and then try.Alternate you can use html form tag rather than codeigniter `form_open`.

Comment: i already complete this form data submission work in html with help of php saving data in db but now boss need to remake in codeigniter thats why facing too much problem i install fresh from website and use it.

Comment: Need to do a lot of debugging.

Comment: user2936213, i fix the problem of this form now i need to more upgrade this form and for this i post a question if you suggest anything for my guidance.

Comment: Sure.Give me the link.What was the problem of this question?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989811/codeigniter-hidden-input-with-redirect-function)

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is 'welcome' then your url should be 'localhost/welcome'. Also check your mod_rewrite.
**Edit**

I think it will be your php installation, since you said when you removed the php codes, it was working perfectly.

Comment: already check if you check the comments you also see the .httaccess file i pasted.