# codeigniter - hidden input with redirect function

Tags: php, codeigniter

i made a simple form for users to add email & city for newsletter form is working fine and insert data in db, but i use two form because of english and arabic users now i need to add hidden input on both form secondly i need redirect as per the hidden input what can i do please suggest and guide me to fix this problem, for convenience i share complete codes as files.

**ar_signup.php in views**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="assests/css/ar/ar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
  </head>
  <body>        
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="columnout" class="left">
        <div id="column">
            <a id="lanLnk" href="http://english.halalat.com" title="english" target="_blank">english</a>  
            <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
            <?php echo form_open('user/create_user'); ?>                   
                <div class="OptForm">
                    <label>
                        <span style="color:white; font-size: 13pt"><img src="assests/images/ar/email.png" class="opt1">الايميل</img></span>
                        <input id="email" type="text" name="email">
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span style="color:white; font-size: 13pt"><img src="assests/images/ar/city.png" class="opt2">المدينة</img>
                        </span>
                        <select name="city" id="city">
                            <option value="jeddah" selected="selected">جدة</option>
                            <option value="riyadh">الرياض</option>
                            <option value="dammam">الدمام</option>
                            <option value="makkah">مكة المكرمة</option>
                            <option value="madina">المدينة</option>

                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input id="submit-btn" name="Submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">

                    </label>
                </div>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?> <!-- end of Form -->
            <div class="footer_terms">
             <a href="#" target="_blank">تسجيل الدخول</a>
              | <a href="#" target="_blank">سياسة الخصوصية</a>
              | <a href="#" target="_blank">الشروط والأحكام</a>
             </div>
              <div class="social">
             <a href="http://www.facebook.com/halalat" target="_blank"><img src="assests/images/ar/facebook.png" width="48" height="48"></a>
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com/halalatksa" target="_blank"><img src="assests/images/ar/twitter.png" width="48" height="48"></a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="assests/images/ar/linkedin.png" width="48" height="48"></a>
            </div>
             <!-- end of Footer -->
            </div><!-- end of Cloumn Left -->
    </div>
    <div id="background-img" style=" margin-top:0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; top:0px; left:0px; padding:0px; right top no-repeat; position:relative; z-index:1;">
     <img src="assests/images/ar/bg_ar2.jpg" width="1181" height="650" alt=""></div>



</div><!-- end of Wrapper -->

  </body>
</html>
```

**ar_thanks.php in view**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Souq.com,Deal,Day,Best Prices">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Halalat Landing Page</title>
    <link href="assests/css/ar/thankyouar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="assests/css/ar/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="columnout" class="left">
            <div id="column">
                <a id="lanLnk" href="http://english.halalat.com" title="english" target="_blank">english</a>                        
                <div class="footer_terms">
                 <a href="#" target="_blank">????? ??????</a>
                  | <a href="#" target="_blank">????? ????????</a>
                  | <a href="#" target="_blank">?????? ????????</a>
                 </div>
                  <div class="social">
                 <a href="http://www.facebook.com/halalat" target="_blank"><img src="assests/images/ar/facebook.png" width="48" height="48"></a>
                <a href="http://www.twitter.com/halalatksa" target="_blank"><img src="assests/images/ar/twitter.png" width="48" height="48"></a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="assests/images/ar/linkedin.png" width="48" height="48"></a>
                </div>
                 <!-- end of Footer -->
                </div><!-- end of Cloumn Left -->
        </div>
        <div id="background-img" style=" margin-top:0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; top:0px; left:0px; padding:0px; right top no-repeat; position:relative; z-index:1;">
         <img src="./images/bg_ar2.jpg" width="1181" height="650" alt=""></div>



    </div><!-- end of Wrapper -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

**user.php in controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class User extends CI_Controller {

         function __construct()
         {
           parent::__construct();
         }
    public function create_user()
    {
        // field name, error message, validation rules
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'trim|required');     

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('ar_signup');
        }
        else
        {           
            $this->load->model('Users_model');

            //if($query = $this->Users_model->create_member())
            {
                $this->load->view('ar_thanks');         
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**users_model.php in model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Users_model extends CI_Model
    {


    function create_member()
    {
            $new_member_insert_data = array(
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'city' => $this->input->post('city'),                           
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_member_insert_data);
            return $insert;


    }//create_member
}
```

Comment: Do you want o add a hidden field and redirect based on that value?

Comment: i need to add input field in form when the controller get input hidden field redirect the thanks page as per mentioned hidden.
1- Arabic Thanks Page ( ex: hidden input ar )
2- English Thanks Page ( ex: hidden input en )

Comment: In your both form, add hidden field under the `<?php echo form_open('user/create_user'); ?>` line. So you can get it in controller.

Comment: <input id="lang" name="ar" type="hidden" value="ar">
this i mention in both form first?

Comment: So what is the problem?Did you tried Kumar_v's suggesstion?

Comment: i ask this input i mention in form first, then as per your mention below answer i follow , i am very new for php & codeigniter thats why ask again  and again sorry.

Comment: You are having two `ar_signup.php` and two `ar_thanks.php` views?in both one for english and one for arabic?

Comment: ar_signup.php for user registration & ar_thanks.php after submission a form, and both are in view same as for english i use, en_signup.php & en_thanks.php they are also in view now need to control this form with hidden input in both forms when controller recv ar go on ar_thanks , if recv en go on en_thanks

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ar_signup.php` form mention `<?php echo form_hidden('language', 'ar');?>` just after the `form_open()`.
Similarly in `en_signup.php` form mention `<?php echo form_hidden('language', 'en');?>` just after the `form_open()`.

Since, as I guess, your both signup forms are redirecting to `create_user()` function in `user` controller, just add :

```
if($this->input->post("language")=="ar")
{
   $this->load->view('ar_thanks');
}
else
{
  $this->load->view('en_thanks');
}
```

wherever you want to load thanks page.

Comment: `public function create_user()
 {
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'trim|required');    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->load->view('ar_signup');
  }
  else
  {   
   $this->load->model('Users_model');
   if($this->input->post("language")=="ar")
  {
   $this->load->view('ar_thanks');
  }
  else
  {
  $this->load->view('en_thanks');
  }   
   if($query = $this->Users_model->create_member())
   {   
    $this->load->view('ar_thanks');  
  }
   
  }  
 } 
}`

Comment: please tell me mistake in this code when i run it shows again create_user link

Comment: please wait problem in wamp htaccess so i will check this online any of problem i will update you.

Comment: Ok.If this solves your issue dont forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on left :)

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

i mention these lines in httaccess, and now i provide you the link you see still the problem there [link](http://giftotravel.pk/landingpage)

Comment: you are here my teacher and from you i learn alot and i knew it for answer acceptance for you i will do it now.

Comment: Thanks! You want to remove index.php by .htaccess? and what is the problem in this link?

Comment: when you submit the form, url go again to user/create_user but not redirect on ar_thanks.php this is mistake how i rectify.

Comment: Have you checked the database is the entry getting inserted?

Comment: in controller add redirect to load view how is it possible ?

Comment: on local wamp db update no problem in code but now to add redirect.

Comment: instead of `redirect()` i used directly `$this->load->view`

Comment: but when i use this load facing problem in css thats why i ask for redirect.

Comment: what is your css problem?this is nothing related to css

Comment: when i use this load view after submission page go on ar_thanks.php white page with no css & images work let me share a screen short.[link](http://i44.tinypic.com/5qsuc.jpg)

Comment: for testing i mention link in ar_thanks.php thanks from fahad you can see a text in screen short.

Comment: n your `ar_thanks.php` use this `<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assests/css/ar/thankyouar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assests/css/ar/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">`

Comment: superb its work, now i complete working on en side if any of problem i will post , thankyouuuuuuuuuu so very very much i dont have too much repu points so i cannot up the vote for this post!

Comment: Its ok! you got it worked thats fine :) and you can upvote since you are having 15 repo :)

Comment: i done ittt yayyyyyyyyyy thankyou so much , because if you not guide & help me out i dont think its possible to sort it out!

Comment: everything fixed, now start working for mobile version...huff!

Comment: user2936213, Can i share here a complete application for user guidance

Comment: Sorry but I didnt understood what you want?

Comment: I ask now the form is ready for languages login and also data submit in dabtabase so i can share complete project code for public guide.

Comment: you can share it on github.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060203/css-html-fixing-of-background-via-css)  CSS Fix for website

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086233/codeigniter-controller-load-multiple-views) Multi Views In Controller

Answer (score 0):

in your both forms, add hidden field as below.

```
form_hidden('lang', 'en/ar');
```

In controller, check `lang`

```
if($this->input->post("lang")=='ar')
{
  // redirect to arabic thanks page
}
else
{
   // redirect to english thanks page
}
```