# codeigniter - controller load multiple views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a website but in two versions one for normal users and one for the mobile users and for both I made view page and also with multilanguage options, first I add in controller

```
public function index()
    {
        if ($this->input->get("lang") =="en")
            $this->load->view('en_signup');
        else
            $this->load->view('ar_signup');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
}
```

I made pages with name of `marabic.php` and `menglish.php` for mobile users now first I need to load these pages also but not mix with the original/default view pages, because I already mention java cript in default view page when its detect mobile user it redirect to `m.domainname.com` now I want to figure out this issue, please suggest.

Comment: this means if your language is english you need to load `en_signup.php` for website and `menglish.php` if mobile user, same for arabic.right?

Comment: yes you are right, right now what the controller do default open form in arabic okey on arabic form i mention english anchor so if any one need english click and go on english, now i made a mobile version for the same website so i need to control two views , even i use java script for mobile detection in default view when url is open it check if user from mobile redirect it.
when i use to load the view so it mix both mobile and normal view.

Comment: check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('user_agent');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    if ($this->input->get("lang") =="en"){
        if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
          $this->load->view('menglish');
        } else {
          $this->load->view('en_signup');
        }
    } else {
        if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
          $this->load->view('marabic');
        } else {
          $this->load->view('ar_signup');
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/6h6BUxT0) please check the user.php controller because here i fix same as above thanks for the both versions

Comment: your link is having old code only.you did not add the above code.

Comment: its old code of user.php controller for thanks i ask can i add the same code as you mention above?

Comment: in the user.php how i add for the mobile version because this code only for the default view

Comment: i ask i make a new function for mobile or in the same function i try the code?

Comment: right now dont have online hosting that's why i made and ask check the syntax and loop its fine.

Comment: Yeah it seems fine :)

Comment: oh yay! thanks to you for pushing me to make a logic :D

Comment: one more thing i wana ask, after the submission of form in database i wana generate confirmation from our side

Comment: so for that you can use `$this->session->set_flashdata();`. For more details see this: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/GBMUSvPp) 
Please check The code as i discuss with you, now the default page when i submit the form it shows no page found even data not submitting in db please suggest old working default page also off.

Comment: Where did you load `$this->load->library('user_agent');` library?

Comment: In Controller Two Files I have welcome.php & user.php both file codes i share.

Comment: you need to load this library in users.php controller also if you are using `$this->agent->is_mobile()` in users.php controller

Comment: `class User extends CI_Controller {
   function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
   $this->load->helper('form');
   $this->load->helper('url');
   $this->load->library('user_agent');`

I load library but when i submit form shows page not found.

Comment: this code not work , quit this tommorrow i will made again from scratch and see if i am stuck any where i will buzz you, thankyou so much

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109216/parse-error-in-controller-file) Please suggest

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201276/codeigniter-email-class-registration-after-submission) please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect if a user is visiting from a mobile device by using CodeIgniter's [User Agent](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html) library.

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');

if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
 // Load mobile view
}
```

Comment: `public function index()
 {
  if ($this->input->get("lang") =="en")
   $this->load->view('en_signup');
  else
            $this->load->view('ar_signup'); 
  $this->load->library('user_agent');
  if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
  if ($this->input->get("language") =="english")
   $this->load->view('menglish');
  else
            $this->load->view('marabic');   
 }
 $this->load->helper('url');
 }
}`

its correct?

Comment: You don't need me to write your code for you, surely? You'll need curly braces around your if/else statements.

Comment: when i load the view only for mobile it mix index view page and mobile view two views mix it how can i sort out

Comment: Put curly braces around your statements and only call a single view. `if ($statement) { //do something }`

Comment: ' public function index()
 {
  if ($this->input->get("lang") =="en")
   $this->load->view('en_signup');
  else
            $this->load->view('ar_signup'); 
 }
  public function mobile()   
  if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
  $this->load->view('marabic');     
  else
         $this->load->view('ar_signup'); 
 }
  $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->library('user_agent');'

now its correct?

Comment: No. You need to go to be very basics of programming. Pasting that into my editor shows several syntax errors.